# How long do I have to be out of the Philippines to get a new 30 day tourist visa after leaving?

Tags: visas, philippines, repeat-visits

Because return flights are a lot cheaper than two directs - and because I want to go to a few countries in Asia - I'm planning to book a return flight from London to Manila, to stay in Philippines for 20 days (on a free 30 day visa) - but then I'm planning to fly to some other countries and come back to Manila to get my flight home.

Do you know how long I would need to be out of the Philippines to be eligible for a second visa in order to fly back?

Answer (score 1):

If your passport is British this is possible:

> If you are a citizen of one of the countries that don't require a visa for stay up to 30 days then yes you can go to another country and go back to the Philippines and get another 30-day visa-free stay so actually you can stay for a total of 2 months if you want.

- https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g294245-i3256-k11700124-Can_i_leave_and_return_the_philipines_if_within_30_days-Philippines.html